# Apache solr filter based on array values

Tags: 7, search

Has anyone succeeded in filtering array values using Apache solr? I have nids as an array, programmatically I want to use the array to filter the solr based on the 'entity_id'.

I tried something like

```
  $solr = apachesolr_get_solr();
  $query = apachesolr_drupal_query("custom", array('q' => ''),'sort_label asc', 'search/site');
  $query->addFilter('entity_id', '[10915 11013]');
  $response = $query->search();
```

But I don't get the desired results, somewhere the apachesolr_search or apachesolr module seems to be adding quotes to the filter values something like

```
webapp=/solr path=/select params={sort=sort_label+asc&start=0&q=&json.nl=map&wt=json&fq=entity_id:"[10915+11013]"&rows=10} status=500
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Just a small change to what Clive suggested will solve the issue.

```
$query->addParam('fq', "entity_id:(10915 OR 11013)");
```

The above code gives me the expected response, i.e., result of node 10915 and 11013.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

`addFilter` can't guess what your intentions are, so it assumes you're passing a string value for the filter - which is then properly escaped so Solr doesn't misinterpret special chars as part of it.

If you want a more complex condition, you need to go a bit more manual:

```
$query->addParam('fq', "entity_id:[10915 11013]");
```

(that's assuming `field:[x,y]` is valid Solr query syntax for an `IN` operation, I don't know that it is; you might have to use a basic `OR` instead).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Clive, but I still get the same response webapp=/solr path=/select params={sort=sort_label+asc&start=0&q=&json.nl=map&wt=json&fq=entity_id:"[10915+11013]"&rows=10} status=500 in solr. FYI, I am using solr 3.5